# Simple $lookup "left join" of the ObjectId of two collections not working in Mongo DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, oboe.js

I am using Mongo DB Atlas with node.js and oboe (oboe streams the results to html). I am new to this all, just learning all these technologies, so explaining in simpler terms will be appreaciated.

The goal is to do a $lookup between two collections, in this case, the collection of 'review' to 'place'. I've researched similar answers, but the either didn't work or were using strings, not ObjectIds.

It's quite simple, just connect the ObjectIds of both of the collections, but I am not able to pull the data out from the "left joined" collection of 'places' when using oboe (see oboe code at bottom, FWIW).

Here is a look at a document from both collections, then the code. What am I doing wrong? I have tried converting them to strings and joining with .toString() and .str, plus put 'place_id.ObjectId' and '_id.ObjectId' for localField and foreignField. Another thing too, is how can I see what is in the cursor to know what I am getting?  debug(cursor.ToArray()) didn't work. Thanks in advance.

```
review
({
  "_id": { "$oid": "5fd27fd9647f7bb815c4c946" },
  "place_id": { "$oid": "5fbc37c4fc13ae680b00002b" }, // connect this...
  "user_id": { "$oid": "5fbc10ecfc13ae232d000068" },
  "title": "Black Forest -- unforgettable!",
  "description": "The forest was great.",
  "score": { "$numberInt": "5" }
}
```

```
place
{
  "_id": { "$oid": "5fbc37c4fc13ae680b00002b" }, // connected to _id above
  "name": "Black Forest (Schwarzwald)",
  "category": "activity",
  "city": "Freiburg",
  "country": "Germany",
  "description": "The Black Forest (German: Schwarzwald [ˈʃvaʁtsvalt] (About this soundlisten)) is a large forested mountain range.]",
  "image": { "filename": "1607629020164_black_forest.jpg", "mime": "image/jpeg" },
  "state": ""
})
```

```
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  debug('get all reviews api');
  try {
    const q = req.query.q;
    const collation = { locale: 'en_US', strength: 1 };

    const matchStage = {};
    if (q) {
      matchStage.$text = { $search: q };
    }
    const pipeline = [
      {
        $match: matchStage,
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'place',
          localField: 'place_id',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'place',
        },
      },
    ];
    const connection = await db.connect();
    const cursor = connection.collection('review').aggregate(pipeline, { collation: collation });


    // write the JSON file
    res.type('application/json');
    res.write('[\n');
    for await (const doc of cursor) {
      res.write(JSON.stringify(doc));
      res.write(',\n');
    }
    res.end('null]');
  } catch (err) {
    sendError(err, res);
  }
});
```

The cursor goes to oboe and becomes an 'item'. I would expect to use a template string such as `{item.place.name}` to get the data when putting this into html. That's how I would access it, right?

```
    const performSearch = () => {
      seen = 0;
      $('stream-data-spinner').removeClass('d-none');
      $('#search-results').html('');
      const formData = $('#search-place-form').serialize();

      oboe('/api/review?' + formData)
        .node('![*]', (item) => {
          if (item) {
            chunk.push(item);
            if (chunk.length >= 1000) {
              showChunk(chunk);
            }
          }
          return oboe.drop;
        })
        .done((_) => {
          // show the last chunk
          showChunk(chunk);
          // hide the spinner
          outputSpinner.classList.add('d-none');
        })
        .fail((res) => {
          // show the error
          outputSeen.textContent = `ERROR: network error`;
          outputSeen.classList.add('text-danger');
          outputSpinner.classList.add('text-danger');
        });
    };
```

Comment: You should definitely be using Atlas Search for this query. Do you have a free Sandbox Account there? I can write the query.

Comment: I have the sample data sets if that is what you mean, for example one of them has mock airbnb data. However, I believe my $lookup is working because I can see the JSON.tringify in a debug, but I can't access the data I need in what the results put out in oboe. I think the answer by Ray below could be the right path, that I need to use $unwind.

I'd like that very much if you could write the query.

Comment: I believe I have it, see with Ray's solution there, the $unwind did it for me.

Comment: Oh you were looking for left join? My mistake. I was just going through all MongoDB tagged items that included `$search`. For many search operations, `$search` as the first aggregation stage is faster. This case is a unique one and I honestly didn't read through it sufficiently.  I will write a query. One sec.

Comment: Well, it looks like you would need two queries because you are looking to join two collections, unless you consolidated them with materialized views. Are you in 4.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your MongoDB aggregation query, your `place` field is an array. You may want to [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) it to flatten it into object for your oboe code to access it.

Comment: Reading about $unwind now. I am  using oboe now and writing all kinds of weird template strings to no avail, like ${item.place[0].city and several other variations. Does this seem like $unwind is still the solution?

Comment: That was it. Just added after the lookup: `` {
        $unwind: '$place',
      },`
`` and that did the job.

Comment: I think this depends on your usage of the aggregation result. From my experience, I don't prefer to keep fields in array type as I want to avoid doing heavy handling on array fields . The code will become convoluted and could be not performant in that way. Usually, I will $unwind them after $lookup to utilize the [$lookup + $unwind optimatization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#lookup-unwind-coalescence).